Using the compare() function with strings
I have to use a binary search to find a movie that the user inputs, however, when doing certain movies, or movies that aren't in the list, the search loops forever. I was told it was cause I can't use ">" or "<" with strings and I have to use the compare() function but I am having trouble.
int main() { ...
pos = findMovieTitle(MovieArray, MOVIES_SIZE, Movies.title);

        if(pos == -1) {
            cout << Movies.title << " was not found" << endl << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "Title: " << MovieArray[pos].title << endl;
            cout << "Year Released: " << MovieArray[pos].year << endl;
            cout << "Revenue: " << MovieArray[pos].revenue << endl << endl;
        }
...
}

int findMovieTitle(const Movies topMovies[], const int SIZE, string title) {
    int first = 0;
    int last = SIZE - 1;
    int middle;
    int pos = -1;
    bool found = false;
    
    while (!found && first <= last) {
        middle = (first + last) / 2;
        
        if(topMovies[middle].title == title) {
            pos = middle;
            found = true;
        } else if (topMovies[middle].title.compare(title) > 0) {
            last = middle - 1;
        } else {
            first = middle - 1;
        }
    }
    
    return pos;
}

I searched it up and saw that if the first string was greater, it returned a positive integer so I tried this but it did not fix it.

I was told it was cause I can't use ">" or "<" with strings -- Who told you that?   You are already using == to compare strings, so > and < also exist.  if (topMovies[middle].title > title) works just fine.

Don't do C in C++ code. For references to arrays use std::span.  auto findMovieTitle(std::span< constMovies> topMovies, const string title);. You can later switch to std::vector in the caller without changing this function. But I would primarily try std::ranges::binary_search or std::binary_search instead.

This line:
        first = middle - 1;

Needs to be:
        first = middle + 1;

That's very likely the root cause of your bug and infinite looping.
And if you're required to use compare for your homework assignment, you can optimize around doing only one comparison instead of two. I suspect compilers will optimize your code anyway with the right compiler flags enabled, but here's a subtle optimization.
    int cmp = topMovies[middle].title.compare(title);
    if(cmp == 0) {
        pos = middle;
        found = true;
    } else if (cmp > 0) {
        last = middle - 1;
    } else {
        first = middle + 1;
    }


Is that really supposed to be first = middle - 1; in your optimized example? (suspect copy issue)

It should indeed be first = middle + 1;.

@DavidC.Rankin - good catch.

Not like I've never done that :)
